# Nodemon start script and running eslint

Tags: node.js, eslint, nodemon

I'm starting a project in Vue.JS and I'm a little new to nodemon.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run eslint'",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12"
  }
}
```

I can get nodemon to run through app.js with "nodemon src/app.js". I've tried a whole bunch of combinations after --exec and haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is (in package.json and windows):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "start-dev": "nodemon --exec \"npm run lint && node index\"",
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

This works pretty fine for your use-case.

`nodemon src/app.js --exec "npm run lint && node"`

or you can write nodemon.json file in your root directory

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/*.spec.js", ".git", "node_modules"],
  "exec": "npm run lint && node src/app.js"
}
```

Comment: With your code I run `npm start` and I get "''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." if I run `npm run` I get "Lifecycle scripts included in server:
  start
    nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'

available via `npm run-script`:
  lint
    eslint **/*.js"

Comment: @BrianPatrick for Windows you need to escape the quotes correctly: `--exec \"npm run lint && node\""`

Answer (score 1):

Im using `nodemon` version 1.19.4. You just missed the "events" key. The right way would be to create a `nodemon.json` in your root folder like that, then a `lint` script in your `package.json` with your `lint` command:

```json
{
  "watch": [ "src" ],
  "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/*.spec.js", ".git", "node_modules"],
  "events": {
    "restart": "npm run lint"
  }
}
```

[Here you can check about Nodemon Events.](https://medium.com/netscape/nodemon-events-run-tasks-at-server-start-restart-crash-exit-93a34c54dfd8)

When using events you don't need to manually handle your application state (restart, crash, node execution, etc), just put what you want to happen when `nodemon` refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a custom script for a while now which I finally published to npm.
Check it out here: https://github.com/theoephraim/lint-fix-nodemon

This helps avoid double restarts when eslint fixes your files as well as not failing on the initial run if eslint has fatal errors.

Hope it helps!